# Вывести элементы вектора через запятую (задача)

Tags: c++, vector

Задача из Практикума:

В переменной vec хранится вектор строк. Нужно вывести его элементы через запятую
После последнего элемента запятую выводить не нужно.
В случае пустого вектора вывести только endl

Попробовал решить, но ставится только одна запятая.

```cpp
bool is_first = true;
for (auto el : some_vector){
    cout << el;
    if (is_first == true){
        cout << ", ";
    } 
    is_first = false;
}
cout << endl;
```

Придерживаюсь этого алгоритма:

Создайте цикл, в котором будете выводить элементы.
Перед элементом в теле цикла выводите , . Но в первой итерации выводить запятую не нужно, поэтому вывод должен быть заключён в if внутри тела цикла.
Перед циклом создайте переменную bool is_first, изначально равную true. Она будет равна true только на первой итерации и позволит не выводить запятую в первый раз.
В теле цикла проверьте значение is_first. Если оно истинно, выведите текст , .
В конце тела цикла измените значение is_first на false — так следующая итерация начнётся со значением false в этой переменной.
endl должен выводиться один раз после тела цикла.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где сделал ошибку(и)?

Comment: Прочитайте алгоритм еще раз, там же все написано. *"**Перед** элементом в теле цикла выводите `,`"*, *"в **первой** итерации выводить запятую **не** нужно"*.

Comment: В первой итерации is_first равно true и при проверке запятая выводится. Хотя как раз не должна.

Comment: Вам нужно поменять местами вывод элемента и вывод запятой, у вас же написано в алгоритме, что сначала выводится запятая и только потом элемент. Так же прочитайте свое условие для вывода запятой, у вас выводится запятая только в том случае если элемент - первый

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно переделать алгоритм так, чтобы он сначала проверял, не первый ли это элемент, а затем уже выводить запятую, если потребуется, и сам элемент.

Как минимум все условия задачи соблюдаются, и при этом вывод производится нормально.

```cpp
bool is_first = true;
for (auto el : some_vector){
    if (is_first == false){
        cout << ", ";
    } 
    cout << el;
    is_first = false;
}
cout << endl;
```

Comment: Еще `is_first = false` подвинуть в `else`, и будет совсем красиво.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat "**В конце тела цикла** измените значение is_first на false — так следующая итерация начнётся со значением false в этой переменной." — да, можно и с else, но я не знаю, можно ли отступать от ТЗ или же нельзя, поэтому этот момент решил оставить

Answer (score 1):

```
bool is_first = true;
    for (auto el : some_vector) 
    {
        if (is_first)
        {
            std::cout << el;
            is_first = false;
        }
        else std::cout << ", " << el;
    }
    std::cout<< std::endl;
```